# I can not find the WPF App (.Net Core) template in visual studio 2019?

Tags: wpf, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I have read all the topics on this.  I actually have it working on Visual Studio on one computer. I have used the installer to install the necessary work loads.  I have tried downloading dotnet 5 and .net core 3.1.  It just will not show up on the create projects window of Visual Studio. I only get WPF App(.NET Framework) or WPF App(.NET). I want to make WPF .netcore applications and this is a roadblock.  Else, I can only make .Net Framework applications that can not be used for multi-platform development. I can make a core project in the Visual Studio with wpf .netcore template and then move it to my other computer and it works fine.  The template just will not show up for core project (wpf).  I am taking a wpf udemey course and it tells of the advantages of using core wpf in many applications.

Comment: that's a pity but there isn't net core wpf application( it can't be crossplatform if you use WPF.

Comment: I have a choice for WPF App (.Net Core) in Visual Studio 2019 on one of my computers. It works fine on that computer.  But, the new install doesn't seem to have the template.

Comment: Have you tried what you get when you choose `WPF App(.NET)`? What formely was called .NET Core is now .NET (5).

Comment: On my VS 16.8.3 the `WPF App(.NET)` template creates a project with `<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>`. In order to *actually* use .NET 5 you would have to change that to `<TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>`

Comment: That is it! Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to adjust the settings under Environment > Preview Features.  Specifically `Show all .NET Core templates in the New projects dialog` and `Use preview of the .NET Core SDK` And you must have installed the .NET 5 preview. SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Open the V***isual Studio Installer*** (This is for VS2022, but the same should apply for 2019.)

Add the "***.NET desktop development***" Workload (see image below) which allows you to "Build WPF, Windows Forms, and console apps using C#, VB, & F#... "

[image: VS 2022 Installer... Check box for '.NET desktop development']

And then it will appear (or should):

[image: .NET is how they reference Core now.]